# Array of objects or Object of objects in NodeJS for in memory simple data base

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I want to store in memory an object (let's call it *payload*) like this one:

```
{
   id: 123,
   foo: { bar: "some data" }
}
```

The first idea was simply to do:

```
let objectCollection = [];

objectCollection.push(payload);
```

And that works. BUT, some parts of the application will manipulate that array, adding or removing objects from it, here's an example of how I do it:

```
class objectCollection {

    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
    }

    add(payload) {
        this.data.push(payload);
    }

    removeById(id) {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if(this.data[i].id === id) {
                this.data.splice(i, 0);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

    findOne(id) {
        let data = this.data.filter((el) => {
            return el.id === id
        });

        return data[0] || null;
    }

}
```

As you can see this collection class can be an abstract class other classes can extend, its a very rudimentary pseudo memory DB like thing... A few things I don't like though:

1. Race conditions may occur on multithread, one process found the index for element X and before doing the splice function some other process added a new element shifting all elements index, so the consequence is that process 1 deletes/splices the wrong element.
2. To find or to remove elements I need to iterate the array.

I'm not expecting more than 5k elements in the array, so iteration should not be a problem, and I really dont want to complicate the application using Redis or similar in memory databases that require another binary to monitor. What if instead of using an array to store the elements I use an Object, like this:

```
...
constructor() {
  this.data = {};
}

add(payload) {
  this.data[payload.id] = payload.foo;
}

remove(id) {
  if(typeof this.data[id] !== 'undefined')
    delete this.data[id];
}
```

This will clean up a bit the code and remove the iteration. What do you think about this approach? are there any important implications on my decision about migrating from array to object?, can you suggest improvement or libraries that already do this?

Comment: It seems obvious that if you have unique ids you should store them in an object keyed to id. I’m not sure why you are worrying about multiple threads in a Node app, though. This may be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you just want advice about the approach.

Comment: You can actually use a Map http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/map it already provides the CRUD API and the implementation should already be "optimized". I don't think you should worry about race condition, there is only one thread in nodejs (unless you decide to spawn different processes, but in that case a persistent db should be more adapted ... )